# In the context of speech, is there a word like *dictator* to describe a person who *dictates* (a person who speaks, says something, etc: *dictator*)?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-usage, adjectives

In the context of speech, is there a word like *dictator* to describe a person who *dictates* (a person who speaks, says something, etc: *dictator*)?

I tried to research this, but it seems that the word *dictator* is used only to describe a person who behaves in an autocratic way.

Comment: Dictator: a person who dictates, as to a secretary. https://www.dictionary.com/browse/dictator - Dictator: 3. One who dictates: These initials are those of the dictator of the letter. https://www.thefreedictionary.com/dictator

Comment: @user070221 Oh wow, I didn't even see the last definition. Thanks for that.

Comment: Dictate meaning "Say or read aloud (words to be typed, written down, or recorded on tape) - ‘I have four letters to dictate’" is not mainly AmE; it is perfectly normal in BrE. To avoid (I suppose) unintentional comparisons to Hitler, Mussolini, etc, the person doing it is usually said to be 'giving dictation', and the other person is 'taking dictation'.

Comment: This is actually its original usage: to dictate: *1590s, "to practice dictation, say aloud for another to write down," from Latin dictatus, past participle of dictare "say often, prescribe," frequentative of dicere "to say, speak" (from PIE root *deik- "to show," also "pronounce solemnly"). Sense of "to command, declare, or prescribe with authority" is 1620s, as is the meaning "be the determining cause or motive of."* https://www.etymonline.com/word/dictate#etymonline_v_8540

Comment: 'Dictator' was also a Latin word, though in ancient Rome a dictator was given absolute power _temporarily_, to see the nation through a crisis. See the link given by user070221 and click on 'dictator'.

Comment: I believe the most natural (modern) word is "speaker".